# angular primeng multiselect show [object][object] in header

Tags: angular, primeng

angular primeng multiselect show [object][object] in the header, instead of the optional label in state of edit/-on focus.

**My code**

```
<p-multiSelect(onFocus)="insertOptions(row,itemProperty.options,itemProperty.insertSelectedOnFocus)" [displaySelectedLabel]="itemProperty.displaySelectedLabel? 'true':'false'" [defaultLabel]="itemProperty.defaultLabel?'Choose':'...'" optionLabel="Name" #con="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="row.Modules" appendTo="body"(onChange)="editItem(row,con,false,$event,true)">
```

I'm sure that the function "insertOptions" doesn't cause the problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask] and consider updating your question. It is going to be next to impossible to help you with the limited information you've provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Angular-Schema. in the prev example, the state was for 'editor', 
I had a tag for state 'body':pTemplate="body"
and the problem disappeared!